# Equivalent of jQuery $(this) in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following code that I need to convert from jQuery to Angular.

```
$(this).append(elem)
```

I converted to the below and it seems to work:

```
angular.element(this).append(elem)
```

But isn't it `this` a jQuery element?

Comment: Please check out [What is the difference between “this”, “$this” and “$(this)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You're using [**jqLite**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) library, so yes, it access `jQuery` behind.

Comment: ^ This is not exactly true. It falls back to jQuery if the latter was loaded before Angular. Otherwise it uses jqLite, a partial implementation of jQuery API.

Comment: The question *But isn't it this a jQuery element?* doesn't make much sense, because it is unknown what `this` is.